# Función repitiendose una vez de más, y hasta repite parte fuera del bucle (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, while

estaba haciendo este programita para probar pero me encuentro con que la primera parte de la función *menu()* se repite una vez no importa el valor que se le meta, lo más raro es que hasta se repite parte que está fuera del bucle, cosa que no tiene sentido... (al menos para mí jeje). Les dejo el código

```
import random

def generador():
    numero_aleatorio = random.randint(1,10)

    return numero_aleatorio

def menu():
    numero_usuario = -5

    print("¡¡Bienvenido!!")

    print("Elija un número del 1 al 10 para saber si es el número que generó la máquina")

    while numero_usuario<0 or numero_usuario>10:
        numero_usuario = int(input("--> "))

        if numero_usuario <0 or numero_usuario>10:
            print("Número fuera de rango, ingrese en el rango correspondiente")
        else:
            break

    return numero_usuario

def comprobador(numero_dusuario,numero_dmaquina):
    while numero_dusuario != numero_dmaquina:
        numero_dusuario = int(input("Error, pruebe de nuevo --> "))

    print(f"¡Muy bien! el número era: {numero_dmaquina}")



menu()
generador()
comprobador(menu(),generador())
```

Foto de lo que me pasa a mí (Como ven, el bucle se repite dos veces sí o sí no importa que el valor sea el correcto para salir de ahí, y hasta se repite el print de arriba que ni siquiera está en el bucle)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás llamando a `menu()` dos veces, una antes de `generador()` y otra dentro de `comprobador()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

def main():
    num_usuario = -1
    num_aleatorio = random.randint(1, 10)
    n = 0 #Número de intentos
    while num_usuario < 1 or num_usuario > 10 or num_usuario != num_aleatorio:
        print("Intenta adivinar el número")
        try:
            num_usuario = int(input("Introduzca un número del 1 al 10:\n--> "))
            n += 1
        except:
            pass
    print("¡Muy bien! Has adivinado el número", num_aleatorio)
    print("Para adivinarlo has necesitado", n, "intentos.")
    repetir = input("¿Quieres adivinar otro número? (Sí/No) ")
    if repetir == "Si" or repetir == "Sí":
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Mientras el número introducido por el usuario sea distinto del generado aleatoriamente, o bien se introduzca un valor que no sea un número del 1 al 10, se repite lo que hay dentro del `while`.

Se usa la variable `n` para contar cuántos intentos se han necesitado para adivinar el número.

Una vez adivinado el número, se ofrece la posibilidad de tratar de adivinar otro número. Para ello hay que introducir Sí (admite con o sin tilde). Cualquier otro valor que se introduzca provocará la finalización del programa.